# MVC DropDownList weird behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to bind a dropdownlist with a ViewBag with following code:
***C#***

```
ViewBag.Type = new List<SelectListItem>() 
{ 
    new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="a" },
    new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="b" }, 
    new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="c", Selected = true }
}
```

***cshtml***

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type", ViewBag.Type as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select type")
```

Also tried

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, ViewBag.Type as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select type")
```

But in above both cases `Type` field is not getting auto selected.

But when i tried

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type1", ViewBag.Type as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select type")
```

Then `Type` field is getting selected by c (value = 3)

In above case i just changed the name (Type -> Type1) and its working !! Any idea ? Why its not working with the actual field name ?

Comment: Maybe you have two fields with the same id="Type" in your view

Comment: no i dont have any other field with duplicate id

Comment: That seems the only explaination of this behavior. After page load, Hit F12 and do Ctrl + F then Search for ** "Type" **. How many does the Search find?

Comment: whenever you wish to pass data for a DropDownList through ViewData or ViewBag, ensure that ViewData / ViewBag property names don't conflict with the form field names. In most of the cases you will need to change the ViewBag property names to something different because form field names are necessary for model binding to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `DropDownList` helper checks if there is `ViewBag.FieldName` and then It's bound automatically.

1. You may change `ViewBag.Type` in `ViewBag.SomethingElse` or
2. use `SelectList`

   ```
       ViewBag.Type = new SelectList()
             { 
                 new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="a" },
                 new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="b" }, 
                 new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="c", Selected = true }
             }

   ///----in your view

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, ViewBag.Type as SelectList, "Select type")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating Dropdownlist same as ViewBag's key name.so it will conflict at runtime.that is why Dropdownlist with ID Type1 works.